# $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions(); fails when called from Zend Helper file - why?

Tags: zend-framework

using ... 
`$this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions();`
.. to retrieve my config settings from application.ini (using Zend Framework 1.11).  this is failing when called from a Zend Helper file but works when called in a controller

why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *getInvokeArg()* method exists for controllers (classes extending **Zend_Controller_Action**), but is not available for action helpers (classes extending **Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract** - I suppose that is what you mean with "Zend Helper file"). You can confirm this in the [Zend Framework API](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/), which is a very useful reference when developing with the Zend Framework.

To call *getInvokeArg()* within an action helper, you must first get the current action controller, which you can do within action helpers by calling the *getActionController()* method. Concluding, within an action helper, the following code will do what you want:

```
$this->getActionController()->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions();
```

The **$this** keyword refers to the current class; as such, within an action helper, **$this** refers to the action helper, and not the controller.

Comment: i get it ... use it in a controller ... send it to a view.  thanks