# Unable to get bootstrap in controller action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a library I've made for use with Zend Framework.  In it, I have `Company/Controller/Action.php` which all application controllers extend.  It's pretty simple and just injects some things into the controllers (like Doctrine's entity manager).

I'm trying to get unit testing to work and have stumbled across an issue where I'm unable to get the bootstrap from within the `Company_Controller_Action` class (which extends `Zend_Controller_Action`):

```
function preDispatch() 
{
  $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
}
```

`$bootstrap` is null at this point.  Anyone have any ideas why?  I've verified that my bootstrap is being called and I can fetch the front controller, but I can't get the bootstrap (through either getInvokeArg or the front controller).

This works in the normal production and development environments.  The testing section of my application.ini just inherits from the production one, so it should be the same.

This is what I'm doing in my `setUp()`:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(
        'testing',
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
    );
    parent::setUp();
}
```

My Bootstrap.php:

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

My phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./Bootstrap.php" colors="true">
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./application</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../application/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".php">../application/Entities</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">../application/modules/default/views</directory>
                <file>../application/Bootstrap.php</file>
                <file>../application/modules/default/controllers/ErrorController.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" title="PrintConcept" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70" />
        <log type="testdox" target="./log/testdox.html" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

**Update:** My `$bootstrap` is no longer null using the above configuration.

Comment: Can you provide some info on your unit test setup? Are you using `Zend_Test_PHPUnit` and bootstrapping your application in the `setUp()` method as per the first code example here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.test.phpunit.html ?

Comment: Added what I'm doing in my `setUp()`.  I'm using the same one as shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug if I remember some few weeks ago which I saw in Zend bug trackers.

Here is the fix which has worked for many:

Initialize Front controller in your Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initFrontController()
{

    $frontControllerInstance = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

    //If bootstrap is NULL or set to null then, set it.
    if(is_null($frontControllerInstance->getParam('bootstrap'))) {
        $frontControllerInstance->setParam('bootstrap', $this);
    }
    return $frontControllerInstance;
}
```

EDIT:

I did a quick Google for the issue. I got a similar [workaround](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8193) (almost the same as I mentioned above) and also this answer on stackoverflow might help you, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219805/this-getinvokeargbootstrap-getoptions-fails-when-called-from-zend-help) it can be called via action helpers.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using triple equals on the null check?

Comment: triple equals are faster than "is_null" :)

Comment: @ArneRie I haven't tested it but, I will believe you ;) For now, I have kept it as is_null. I used triple (equal) before.

Comment: :-) Just wanted to support your "===" decision :-) it is i not realy important

Comment: Actually, it looks as if the help I got in another question, has solved this issue, and presented another problem I need to figure out.

Comment: D'oh.  I'm missing the mssql pdo driver.  Accepted because of the ZF issue tracker link.